# Постоянная работа приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое с помощью jsoup парсит сайт, и если полученное при парсинге значение больше нуля, на устройство приходит уведомление - notification.

Собственно вопрос, как сделать так, что приложение работало постоянно? не зависимо от того заходил ли в него пользователь или нет. 
Нужно чтобы постоянно проверяло значение на сайте. Это нужно для того чтобы если значение изменилось - пользователь тут же получил уведомление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна служба (service) в android

1. Создаете службу.
2. Делаете что бы она запускалась при старте программы и при включении телефона.
3. Службу делаете не отключаемой. Что бы циклически работала.
4. В цикле делаете парсинг сайта и уведомления.

думаю следующие циклы вам помогут:

1. [[Android] Сервисы - это просто.](http://blog.divenvrsk.org/2010/09/android.html?spref=tw)
2. [Взаимодействие между приложением и службой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139831/)
3. [Service. Простой пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer)