# Постоянная работа Activity

Tags: java, android

В приложении имеется UpdateActivity . 
В этом активити выполняется парсинг информации сайта(на jsoup). Мне нужно сделать, чтобы это активити работало постоянно, даже в фоне. Тоесть, спарсило информацию с сайта и тут же снова повторается парсинг.

Как реализовать подобное?

Я пытался так:
Создал AutoStart.java:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

     @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Update.class);
 intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent1);
 }
}
```

В манифест добавил:

```
         <service android:name=".AutoStart" ></service>
     <receiver
android:name=".AutoStart"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>

</receiver>
    <activity android:name="Update"></activity>
```

Но это не привело к желаемому результату.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос был задан ТС час назад http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448332/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: там я спрашивал о работе всего приложения. а здесь о работе определенной активити

Comment: Формулировки вопросов совпадают.

Answer (score 2):

что бы `Activity` не заканчивалось, самое хорошее это 
1. создать в нем `AsyncTask` и запустить (один раз только) 
2. Внутри `AsyncTask` создать бесконечный цикл с параметром `boolean` типо

```
private static boolean canWork = true;
...
while (canWork) {...}
```

если вдруг понадобится остановить меняете значение `canWork=false`

Самое главное!!

**Не делайте Activity не завершающим, лучше сделайте Службу (Service)**